# MIPS32 MARS - put algorithm in function

Tags: function, assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

so i have a little program in mars assembly which gets the greatest common divisor:

```
.text
    addiu $4,$zero,49
    addiu $5,$zero,42
    add $2,$zero,$5

    beq  $4,$zero,label10
loop:   
    beq $5,$zero,label9
    
    slt $9,$5,$4
    bne  $9,$zero,if
    
    slt $10,$4,$5
    bne $10,$zero,else
    beq  $10,$zero,else##if $4 and $5 are equal.
if:
    sub $4,$4,$5
    j endif
else:
    sub $5,$5,$4
    j endif
endif:  
    j loop
label9:
    add $2,$0,$4
label10:
```

The result will be saved in register 2.
Now my second task is, i should change my program so that my algorithm is some "function"(subprogram), where you can set arguments for register 4 and 5 and the return value in register 2.
My problem now is, i dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what to do in order to turn a snippet of code into a function:

1. Give it a label at the beginning, e.g. `MyFunc`.
2. Put a return at the end: `jr $ra`.
3. Make a test main that calls your function and place this at the beginning of the `.text` section — you want this test main to be what the simulator runs first, so it will call your function — you don't want your function first, because as it is no longer a snippet, but now a function, it should be properly invoked: by passing parameters and return address.  The main also has to properly terminate the program otherwise it will run off the edge and run the function again, but accidentally this time.

```
    .text
    # test main: call MyFunc
    #
    # call function, pass some parameters
    li $a0, 20          # load first arg register
    li $a1, 15          # load second arg register
    jal MyFunc          # the actual invocation 
                        # this jumps to the function, 
                        #   while also passing the return address in $ra

                        # here's where come back to when the function is done:
    move $a0, $v0       # move return value into $a0, so we can print it

    li $v0, 1           # and print
    syscall

    li $v0, 10          # and stop the program
    syscall
#
#
#
MyFunc:                 # start of MyFunc
    # ...               # code of function goes here
    jr $ra              # jump back to the caller by using the return address register
```

---

Suggest using friendly register names instead of the simple numeric names.  (And we should never mix friendly names with the simple numeric ones in the same program.)

Comment: Thank you, after posting this question i have  watched a video on youtube where some1 explained it very well. And i have done it like you did, but i forgot to update my question :)